# Как узнать какие файлы выделены в проводнике или на рабочем столе windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

К примеру я выделяю файл на рабочем столе или в папке, как мне узнать имя файла который я выделил?

Comment: Наверно никак...

Comment: Может это [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193388/) даст понимание, как через COM получить перечень выделенных файлов.